# Adding a circle around a rounded image

Tags: html, css

I created a round-image using following HTML

```
<div class="thumb">
<img src="http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" alt="img">
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.thumb{
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
overflow: hidden;
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

I tried adding a new circle around the rounded image, failed eventually. How am I supposed to do this? Should I create a new `div` and add this rounded image inside it and style that div to make it round? I tried to achieve circled image in this google link https://www.gmail.com/intl/en/mail/help/about.html which is placed right below the slider.
Here is my fiddle of what I've gotten so far http://jsfiddle.net/adityasingh773/rzsmpmc9/

Comment: I went to your fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/rzsmpmc9/ and added just two more lines at the end of your `.thumb` CSS ... `border: 7px solid #eee;` and `box-shadow: 1px 1px 12px 8px #ccc;` and that came pretty close to the page you cite. Play with the px spread of the shadow, the shadow position, and the colors, and you should be able to get what you want. No additional markup necessary.
See cvsguimaraes' answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not so elegant solution, because it requires extra-html, but looks pretty fine, imho: (didn't experiment with pseudo-elements, maybe similar result can be achieved).

```
<div class="thumb-wrapper">
<div class="thumb">
<img src="http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" alt="img">
</div> 
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumb-wrapper {
  width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%; 
    background-color:#fefefe;
    position:relative;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:1px solid #dedede;
   -webkit-box-shadow: -5px 4px 19px 0px rgba(143,143,143,1);
-moz-box-shadow: -5px 4px 19px 0px rgba(143,143,143,1);
box-shadow: -5px 4px 19px 0px rgba(143,143,143,1);
}
.thumb{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position:absolute;
    left:8px;
    top:9px;
     box-sizing:border-box;

}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/rzsmpmc9/5/

Answer (score 2):

Tried adding an border?

```
<div>
    <img class="thumb" src="http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" alt="img">
</div>
```

---

```
.thumb{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border:2px solid white;
  box-shadow:0 0 0.5em white;
}
```

**Optionally** you may use an box shadow to produce a solid shadow, since the shadow doesn't compute within the element positioning and size, avoiding interference in your current layout.

Comment: Yes I tried that, but that simply creates extra rounded border around the image and it is square not circle

Comment: @LuckyAli Yeah my initial solution suggested to use an outline, but it doesn't work with rounded corner. Answer updated already...

Comment: this is the same solution like indubitablee gave, but I wanted to achieve some padding between border and rounded image. How do I do that?

Comment: In that case, you can use [two box shadows](http://jsfiddle.net/Kredit/j5zfqdmn/).

Answer (score 1):

you can simply add a border to your existing css

```
border: 3px blue solid;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rzsmpmc9/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve same style as the link you have provided if u'll use an image, which is the most plausible way, but if you play with `box-shadow` u will most likely get the same thing.

```
box-shadow:2px 2px 4px green, -2px -2px 4px red;
```

check [this.](http://jsfiddle.net/rzsmpmc9/7/)